# How I fix this URL rewrite issue in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to write SEO friendly clean URLs, using Apache Mod-Rewrite.

My existing URLs look like this:

```
index.php?p=my-page 
index.php?p=my-page&id=3 
index.php?p=my-page&cat=5
index.php?p=my-page&month=201606
```

I have tried it and this is my code sofar in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&id=$2  [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&cat=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&mth=$4 [L,QSA,NC]
```

But, My problem is, when it change 2nd variable name in query string, its always identifying as `id` not `cat` or `mnt`.

Can anybody tell me how fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot have 3 different rules for same pattern: `^([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$` only first of these 3 will execute all the time.

Comment: @anubhava, Thank you for your comment. Then what would be the solution for this?

Comment: You will need to differentiate 3 URLs some other way. May be by using some prefix like `cat/my-page/5`, `month/my-page/123456` etc

Comment: @anubhava, I couldn't get what you have mentioned. Can you kindly elaborate it? Thank you.

Comment: What are the "user friendly" URLs for these 3 "ugly" URLs. (Note that these are "user friendly", not "SEO friendly" URLs. The SE's don't really care.)

Comment: @user3733831: [Read this helpful answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31280108/548225) as it is impossible to write this much in comments